# Script# and WF Xaml files in the same project, can't compile

Tags: xaml, compiler-construction, script#

We have a VS 2010 MVC3 project, targetting .NET 4.0 (machine has .NET 4.5), the project contains a WF Xaml file and related classes. We needed to access jQueryValidation on the serverside, so we added the script# jQueryValidation NuGet package (v 0.7.5.0), we get the following compile error without even using script# yet:

Error 1 XC1020: Build error occurred in the XAML MSBuild task: 'Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ScriptAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.....

The Xaml file contains references to the standard mscorlib, we've attempted to strong reference the Gac library in Xaml, via version #...however its to no vail. The project will only compile once we remove the Script# libraries. Then in an effort to narrow down the problem, we installed the nuget package for script# 0.7.5.1, not the jQueryValidation package, and we are able to compile. Installing the jqueryvalidation package afterwards will result in the same error as before, could this be related to the package being based on 0.7.5.0?

Any hints? we would really like to use script# jqueryvalidation and WF Xaml in the same project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Script# assemblies are meant to be used by script# projects only, i.e. those projects that contain c# code to be compiled into javascript. Your MVC project itself is not a script# project. Likely what you should be doing is creating a separate script# project, to generate script that gets deployed into/via your MVC project.

Specifically script# comes with its own mscorlib with script# specific types not present in the desktop mscorlib assembly.